# ServiceStack C# client Post returns exception

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have defined the following Dtos for a post request

```
[Route("/schedule", "POST")]
public class ScheduleSaveRequest : IReturn<ScheduleSaveResponse>
{
    public OatiSchedule[] Schedule { get; set; }
}

public class ScheduleSaveResponse
{
    public OatiSchedule[] Schedule { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the service method

```
    public ScheduleSaveResponse Post(ScheduleSaveRequest request)
    {
        foreach (var day in request.Schedule)
        {
            //Process array to data server
        }
        var schedule =
             Repo.GetAllSince(request.Schedule[0].Date).ToArray();
        var response = new ScheduleSaveResponse
        {
            Schedule = schedule
        };
        return response;
    }
```

And here is my client call

```
var saveResponse = Client.Post<ScheduleSaveResponse>("/schedule", dto);
```

The client and service are working just fine for a get request, but when I call the client with the Post method, I get a NotImplementedException from the web service.  How do I wire this up correctly?

Comment: Can't see any problem here, is your Service class inheriting from `Service` or `IService`? Also did you know you can API's that make use the implicit `IReturn<T>` type already defined? e.g: `var response = Client.Post(dto)`

Comment: @mythz It inherits from Service.  My request already inherits from IReturn<T>  Are you saying the response should inherit from IReturn<T>?  What other information could I gather to help troubleshoot this?

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't need to specify the Response Type or custom route since `ScheduleSaveRequest` already inherits from `IReturn<T>` i.e. you should be able to use the more terse API: `var response = Client.Post(dto)`. I'm also assuming none of your Services throw `NotImplementedException` right? Does it hit your breakpoint? Also can you post the raw HTTP Headers for this, e.g. using something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or WireShark.

Comment: How do I get Fiddler to monitor the traffic to self-host?

Comment: See the Fiddler docs for [capturing localhost traffic](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost)

Comment: I don't think I have any control over the request uri because ServiceStack is generating it.  So I tried adding the defaultProxy section to the app.config file as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , but VS says the attribute values are invallid.  Something about the datatype of NmToken is an enum.  I will have to troubleshoot this

Comment: If getting the raw HTTP is problematic, could you put together a small/empty stand-alone app that repro's the issue instead? (e.g. on GitHub)

Comment: That is what I am working on now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it turns out that all of the above posted code is just fine. I have a problem deep in the code that supports the service.  I found the problem by catching ServiceStack's WebServiceExtension and it took me right to it.